# Why tab selection arrows from FMX TabControl disappear at runtime?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a TabControl with many tabs. During the design time there is a control artifact like the one the image below where I can scroll the tabs that are not visible, since there is no available space to show them all.

[image: TabControl at design time]

However at runtime it shows up like this:

[[image: TabControl at runtime[2]]

The only way to select the other non visible tabs is using the keyboard arrows when focusing on any of the visible tabs.

The user will not know that there are more hidden tabs with this problem.

The FullSize parameter does not change anything on runtime. Clipchildren, ClipParent, etc does not cause any change.

Comment: I notice that without a style / default style the control looks like it does at design time.

Comment: @brian I am using Frames to create the dialog, so during design time delphi does not apply the default style on frames, only on forms. That is weird. I know there are differences on size etc when style is applyed and i tried taking a look on the definition but could not understand anything.